# how can i define an integer to use it in a matrices function on matlab

Tags: matlab, function, matrix

my goal is to write a matrix function(plymecfunc) that has 3 inputs and 1 output. here is the function i wrote:

```
function[S]= plymecfunc(E1,E2,G12)
int E1;
int S12;
int S11;
int S22;
S11=1/E1;
S12=-V12/E1;
S22= 1/E2;
S66=1/G12;
S = [ S11 S12 0; 0 S22 0; 0 0 S66];
```

the error is:
**??? Input argument "E1" is undefined.**
**Error in ==> plymecfunc at 6**
**S11=1/E1;**

Comment: You are defining a function, so you must call it as a function. `E1 = ...; E2 = ...; G12 = ...; S = plymecfunc(E1,E2,G12);`. Also in matlab you do not need to define variable `int E1`. Please have a read on some matlab basics.

Comment: ok i understand that i don't need to define variables. ut what i really want is S to be a 3X3 matrix with S11,S12,S22,S66 and 0 as its components. so what should i do ? thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to declare the variables (like in C for example).

```
function[S]= plymecfunc(E1,E2,G12)
  V12 = % define V12, or pass as parameter
  S11 = 1/E1;
  S12 = -V12/E1;
  S22 = 1/E2;
  S66 = 1/G12;
  S = [ S11 S12 0; 0 S22 0; 0 0 S66];
end
```

You can also define the S matrix inline.

```
function[S]= plymecfunc(E1, E2, G12)
  V12 = % define V12, or pass as parameter
  S = [ 1/E1,  -V12/E1, 0; 0 1/E2 0; 0 0 1/G12];
end
```

By the way you are missing the V12 variable.